# throw exception does not work inside future.map scala?

Tags: scala, future

```
def testThrowException(number: Int): Future[Int] = {
 if (number == 0) {
     throw new Exception("number is 0")
 else {
     Future{1}
 }
```

for the above function, if i call it with testThrowException(0), i can see the exception error message printed in console
but if i do something like

```
def testThrowException(number: Int): Future[Int] = {
anotherFuture.map {
    if (number == 0) {
        throw new Exception("number is 0")
    } else {
        1
    }
}
```

i am not able to see the exception printed in console
but if i do testThrowException.onFailure, i can see the failure message, is there anything i did wrong here? why the exception is not printed out

Answer (score 5):

`Future` runs in a separate thread so throwing inside a `Future` just crashes that thread whilst leaving the main thread running. For example,

```
object Hello extends App {
  println(s"Starting in main thread called ${Thread.currentThread.getName}...")
  Future(
    throw new RuntimeException(s"I crashed separate thread called ${Thread.currentThread.getName}")
  ).andThen { case Failure(e) => println(e.getMessage) }
  println("I made it!")
}
```

should output

```
Starting in main thread called run-main-e...
I made it!
I crashed separate thread called scala-execution-context-global-253
```

where we see it crashed separate thread named `scala-execution-context-global-253` whilst the main thread `run-main-e` kept running so `I made it!` got printed just fine. On the other hand, the following example throws outside a `Future`

```
object Hello extends App {
  println(s"Starting in main thread called ${Thread.currentThread.getName}...")
  throw new RuntimeException(s"I crashed the main thread ${Thread.currentThread.getName}")
  println("I made it!")
}
```

which outputs

```
Starting in main thread called run-main-d...
[error] (run-main-d) java.lang.RuntimeException: I crashed the main thread run-main-d
```

where we see main thread `run-main-d` crashed before `I made it!` could be printed.

Answer (score 3):

The first function `testThrowException` does not return a Future in the case that it gets a `0` as input. Therefore, the program keeps running until the exception appears.

However, as seen in the source code pasted below, the `Future.map` always returns another future:

```
  def map[S](f: T => S)(implicit executor: ExecutionContext): Future[S] = { // transform(f, identity)
    val p = Promise[S]()
    onComplete { v => p complete (v map f) }
    p.future
  }
```

Just defining a Future does not print out its results and it also does not print exceptions thrown. You would need to define the `onSuccess`, `onFailure`, or `onComplete` to do so. However, if a print statement exists in the body of the Future, then it will execute:

```
def addOne(number: Int): Int = {
    if (number == 0) {
        // you can also print the exception instead of just throwing it.
        throw new Exception("number is 0")
    } else {
        println("success")
        1 + number
    }
}
Future { addOne(1) } // scala.concurrent.Future[Int] = Future(Success(2))
// the above also prints "success"
Future { addOne(0) } // scala.concurrent.Future[Int] = Future(Failure(java.lang.Exception: number is 0))
// the above does not print anything unless the exception is printed before thrown in `addOne`
```

You can also use `onComplete`, to handle both success and/or failure:

```
// prints "got error" plus the stack trace

 - List item

Future {0}.map(addOne).onComplete {
       case Success(value) => println(s"got $value")
       case Failure(t) => println("got error: " + t.getStackTrace.mkString("\n"))
     }
```

Note that the imports used were:

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.util.{Failure, Success}
```

Answer (score 3):

In the 1st example the exception is just that, a naked exception thrown when encountered. It's not significantly different from something like this.

```
def testThrowException(number: Int): Future[Int] = {
  throw new Exception("BOOM!")
  . . . //code to create a Future[Int]
```

The 2nd example throws an exception inside a `Fututre`. The exception is wrapped in a `Future`, causing it to fail. You won't see anything sent to the console but if you inspect the result value you should see what you're looking for.

```
res0: scala.concurrent.Future[Int] = Future(Failure(java.lang.Exception: number is 0))
```